# Entity Framework Error System.__ComObject to EnvDTE.ProjectItem

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, compiler-errors

I tried to add some entities from my db to my Model.tt and I couldn't do it.
the project doesn't recognize the entities and there aren't appear inside of my Model.tt, but the are in the folder of my project.

When I try to add the new tables/entities I got this error:

```
Ejecutando transformación: System.InvalidCastException: No se puede convertir el objeto COM del tipo 'System.__ComObject' al tipo de interfaz 'EnvDTE.ProjectItem'. Ocurrió un error de operación debido a que la llamada QueryInterface en el componente COM para la interfaz con IID '{0B48100A-473E-433C-AB8F-66B9739AB620}' generó el siguiente error: Error al cargar la biblioteca de tipo/DLL. (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY)).

Server stack trace: 
   en System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.GetCOMIPFromRCW(Object objSrc, IntPtr pCPCMD, Boolean& pfNeedsRelease)
   en EnvDTE.ProjectItem.get_FileNames(Int16 index)
   en Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplatingEC2717411E6FD5E7E265CE923A7190B6.GeneratedTextTransformation.EntityFrameworkTemplateFileManager.VsEntityFrameworkTemplateFileManager.ProjectSync(ProjectItem templateProjectItem, IEnumerable`1 keepFileNames)
   en Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplatingEC2717411E6FD5E7E265CE923A7190B6.GeneratedTextTransformation.EntityFrameworkTemplateFileManager.VsEntityFrameworkTemplateFileManager.<.ctor>b__3c(IEnumerable`1 keepFileNames)
   en System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext, Object[]& outArgs)
   en System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.AsyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, IMessageSink replySink)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   en System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.EndInvokeHelper(Message reqMsg, Boolean bProxyCase)
   en System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RemotingProxy.Invoke(Object NotUsed, MessageData& msgData)
   en System.Action`1.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult result)
   en Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplatingEC2717411E6FD5E7E265CE923A7190B6.GeneratedTextTransformation.EntityFrameworkTemplateFileManager.VsEntityFrameworkTemplateFileManager.Process(Boolean split)
   en Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplatingEC2717411E6FD5E7E265CE923A7190B6.GeneratedTextTransformation.TransformText()
   en Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.TransformationRunner.RunTransformation(TemplateProcessingSession session, String source, ITextTemplatingEngineHost host, String& result)
```

Any clue will be of great help!!
Thanks.

Comment: Add entities to Model.tt - what do you mean? Describe the steps you take. Also, could you please translate the exception message? This is an English site.

Comment: My steps were: 1) add the table to db

Comment: I'm Sorry, I don't know why it didn't appear all my comment.
My Steps were:
1) Add the tables in my database
2) In my Model.edmx, right click, and select the option "Update Model from database".
3) and then, there were added the classes (related to my new tables) in the folder of my project, but not in the project and even associated to the Model.tt (TextTemplatingFileGenerator).

So, I cannot use the classes as if its were part of EntityFramework.

A Little bit clear? I Hope anyone can Help me.
Thanks.